# Azure AD (creating custom multi factor authentication instead of using the one provided by Azure)

Tags: azure-active-directory, two-factor-authentication

I am developing an application which uses Azure AD as authentication provider.
Need to implement a two factor authentication for the application.

Is it possible to create our own provider and plugin into azure without using the one available with Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Azure AD doesn't support to use the third-party MFA authentication provider.

However we are also could build multi-factor authentication into custom apps with Azure AD. More detail about this you can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-sdk).